# Traceback AttributeError: module 'pyaudio' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I intalled SppechRecognition and when I worte

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

The above problem occurred.
The same question was asked over here, but the solution didn't help me!
[AttributeError: module 'pyaudio' has no attribute '__version__'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55507226/11589463)
Please help me!

My Terminal Output:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:/Users/samar/OneDrive/Desktop/MAIN/projects/Jarvis/jarvis.py", line 4, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:

File "C:\Users\samar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()

File "C:\Users\samar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 112, in get_pyaudio
    if LooseVersion(pyaudio.__version__) < LooseVersion("0.2.11"):
AttributeError: module 'pyaudio' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: Show a stack trace

Comment: I have updated my question @MadPhysicist. Please review it!!

Comment: Please format it correctly. I can't read that

Comment: What solution end and why didn't it help

Comment: Is it convenient now?

Comment: Please format it as a single code block, you can use triple backticks. Python stack trace are arranged to provide easy access to the info they contain. It would be good of you to preserve it.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55507226/2988730

Comment: Yes I have also attached that question in my question. The problem is similar but I have no file named as pyaudio.

Comment: Add the following on the lines before your `with` statement: `import pyaudio` and `print(pyaudio.__file__)`. Show the output here

Comment: I wrote 
```import speech_recognition as sr,
import pyaudio,
r = sr.Recognizer(),
print(pyaudio.__file__)```

Output came as `None`

Comment: That is an indication that you are loading a module written in C which does not set the attribute. Where do you think pyaudio is installed, and why do you think so?

Comment: ```PS C:\Users\samar\OneDrive\Desktop\MAINY\projects> pip install pyaudio
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in c:\users\samar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.2.11)```

Comment: You're working with conflicting versions here: question is using site packages in `C:\Users\samar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\`. That's not where pyaudio is installed. Make sure you're using the right pip. E.g, `python3.8 -m pip ...`

Comment: So, can I cut paste the library files from conda folder to pip folder?

Comment: No, you should install with the correct pip. The pip that comes with the version of python you are using to run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed the package from [Unofficial Python Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)and ran the code in the terminal. It worked!